# California nutria hunting

Tags: hunting, invasive-species

Does anyone know of an area in california where I could hunt nutria? I've looked on the CDFW articles but there is not much.

Comment: I don't know what to think about this question.  What harm do nutrias do?  Possibly they do a lot, and possibly this is a state agency running amok.

Comment: This is odd.  I thought nutria were a wetland species.  What are they doing in California?  @ab2  This is easy to research - they are a pretty nasty invasive species once established and the parts where they are *do* make use of hunters.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: California is a big and varied place, and we do have wetlands.

Comment: @ab2 - per the map below, the issue is the Central Valley. That is a big time agricultural area with irrigation canals criss crossing it distributing water from the Sierra Nevada to fields across the valley. Nutria cause major damage to the irrigation system, and thus the agriculture. This is clearly not some "state agency running amok", but an effort well supported by the community there. A threat to irrigation is a threat to their livelihood.

Answer (score 5):

I read the same articles, and it sounds like the invasive species management professionals expect to be able to completely eradicate the nutria without needing assistance from the public at hunting them.

They're actively soliciting help from members of the public to report any new sightings of nutria. When they get a new report, they respond by

1. Monitoring the area for nutria, using intensive monitoring methods and equipment (trained nutria-detecting dogs, trail cameras, traps, etc).
2. If they confirm nutria in that area, hunting down and eradicating those nutria.
3. Continuing to monitor the area for as long as necessary to confirm the nutria are completely eradicated.

That intensive of a detection, eradication and monitoring program doesn't usually leave much room for members of the public to help with hunting and eradication. Where they would need that kind of help is if the nutria do get out of hand, and nutria populations increase to the point where they don't have the resources to control them. At that point they might want help from hunters and trappers to keep the populations under control.

What you could do is contact the CDFW and ask if you can volunteer to help with the program. My guess is they have plenty of funding for step 2, so they don't need any help with eradication. But they may welcome help with steps 1 or 3.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I was more looking for advice on were in california they have not been eradicated so I can hunt them for food because I understand that they taste good. And I don't know of any particular spots where I can hunt them an the Internet only really shows vague and general maps that do not conform to eachother. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: My point is that there probably aren't any places like that, but if they exist they're probably constantly changing, and you should directly contact the experts for current information.

Comment: Particularly if you're planning to eat them, you would want to find out if the ongoing nutria control activities include putting out poisoned bait. Obviously you would not want to eat a nutria which had been poisoned. Hence, needing direct communication with the CDFW.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Fellas.. I also read DFW’s article and figured out where to go by looking at this map. All that’s needed is to get the proper permissions if land is private